# Beamer image not centered

Tags: beamer, graphics

The following code:

```
\frame[plain]
{
  \frametitle{}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{1.jpg}
}
```

is resulting in an image which is offset to the right. The left margin is larger than the right margin. Wrapping the `\includegraphics` in a `figure` or `center` environment does not solve the problem.

How can I center the image in beamer?

Comment: Presumably the image is too wide. Check the log file (*.log) for corresponding warnings. Scale the image to text width if necessary.

Comment: Is the image wider than the text width? try `[width=.75\textwidth]` instead of using `scale`

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: The image is appearing on the page with space all around it. It's just that the space on the left is too large so it's not centered.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That resulted in a right margin, which was too wide. Using `[width=1\textwidth]` solved this for many images. Others were solved by placing them in a centering environment and specifying the height.

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on using `scale` key, then find the best value for it. Varying the value in a closed interval (as shown in the following animation) can help you find the best value for the `scale` key.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.1+0.1}{15}{%
\begin{frame}{scale=\n}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=\n]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't insist on using `scale`. I just thought it was the best way. I tried a few different scale sizes and a left margin was still present in all cases.

Comment: Note: Adjust the increment value (2 decimal places should be more than enough, for example `\n=0.01+0.01`) to get more precise scale.